# can someone help me solve a Power Automate Flows forbidden error

Tags: connection, power-automate, account

I am trying to change the connections in a flow to a different account, but I keep getting the following error. Kindly help me figure out how to solve this

[image]

I am not sure what to try kindly help

Comment: You need to provide more information about what the connection is for and how you're changing it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have below things configured for new user account you are trying to use in Power automate flow:

1. The new user account should have license to use "Microsoft Forms" service.
2. Access/permissions to the Microsoft form you are trying to use in flow.